# To show words in a text in bold with SetSpan and a loop

Tags: android, for-loop, xamarin

I have a text and an array (textviewArray) with 7 words. In my text exist these 7 words. I want to show these 7 words in this text in bold.

I have this code but the last word is bold, not all seven words:

```
textviewS.Text = "My Text ....";
strD = new SpannableStringBuilder("My Text ....");
bss = new StyleSpan(TypefaceStyle.Bold);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
     if (textviewS.Text.IndexOf(textviewArray[i]) >= 0)
     {
          strD.SetSpan(bss, textviewS.Text.IndexOf(textviewArray[i]), (textviewS.Text.IndexOf(textviewArray[i]) + textviewArray[i].Length), 0);
     }
 }
 textviewُ.SetText(strD, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
```

Comment: Why not setting textStyle BOLD if you want to show all text as BOLD

Comment: you need to create `bss` inside the loop

Comment: @pskink I put bss in loop and now I see all 7 words are bold. Thank you. Why should we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String text = "text here";
String[] wordsToBold = {"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7"}
SpannableString spanString = FontUtility.getMultiFontText(context, "fonts/myfont.ttf", text, wordsToBold);

public static SpannableString getMultiFontText(Context context, int fontPathFromAssets, String text, String[] wordsToBold){
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    for(String word : wordsToBold) {
        int startIndex = text.indexOf(word);
        while(startIndex >= 0) {
            int endIndex = startIndex+word.length();
            spannableString.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(context, context.getString(fontPathFromAssets)), startIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            startIndex = text.indexOf(word, endIndex + 1);
        }
    }

    return spannableString;
}
```